# How creating parallel work to TestNG + Maven (Suits)

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, testng

Beaten topic, I know. However, all decisions on the network, on this site - they do not give the desired: it is method to perform **multithreaded** **suites**.
At the moment I have found one method to paralleling suites:

```
public class MultipleXmls {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setXmlSuites((List <XmlSuite>)(new Parser("C:\\Users\\S-Kerrigan\\WSI\\Java_ProjectsM_V.003\\Sets\\Suits\\TEST1.xml").parse()));
    testng.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(4);
    testng.run();
}
}
```

But it not deprecated - this method running suits from Java-application. I need to run suits in parallel-mode from Maven.

I have tried use Grid-node subsystem, read docks on Maven and TestNG - nothing have not been able to help me :(

Comment: You didn't read the docs very well, cause take a look here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html (see Running tests in parallel).

Comment: I'm read this doc - they speak how created parallel "tests/methods/class"! It is not "suite"!

If I'm wrong (if I understand not correctly), then please give a working code. Where you will run several parallel suites.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

> ```
>                    <plugin>
>                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>                            <version>9.9.9.9</version>
>
>                            <configuration>>
>                                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
>                                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
>                                    <suitethreadpoolsize>2</suitethreadpoolsize>
>                                    <suiteXmlFiles>
>                                            <suiteXmlFile>testng-vm1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
>                                            <suiteXmlFile>testng-vm2.xml</suiteXmlFile>>
>                                    </suiteXmlFiles>
>                            </configuration>
>
>                    </plugin>
> ```